# Get process ID with python

Tags: python, windows, winapi

How to get the current process id with Python on Windows?

There is this function `os.geteuid()`, but it only works with Linux/Unix. Could someone explain what is the Pythonic way to get the current process id on windows?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Do you really want the process ID?  Then the answer is this:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getpid()
5328
```

on either Windows or Unix ([documentation of `os.getpid`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.getpid)).

`os.geteuid()` doesn't get the process ID, which makes me wonder whether you're really asking a different question...?