# Is there anyway to get process info by PID or name on Windows using Python?

Tags: python, process, pid

I need to get process info by using `PID` or `Name` on Win 10, using **only standard library**.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

I meant all processes, not current...

Comment: What information about the process, specifically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get process ID with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853703/get-process-id-with-python)

Comment: @ThomasLang He's not asking how to get the pid, he's asking how to get additional information regarding the process GIVEN pid or name.

Comment: @cody Oh, my bad, sorry.

Comment: @ThomasLang yes I meant that, thank you

Comment: I still don't understand. You want to get the list of all running processes, their name and pid?

Comment: @cody I want to get listed, and possibly, too get name of process from given PID or get PID from name passed to some method or function in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subprocess

```
from subprocess import getoutput

process_info = getoutput('wmic process where "name like \'%{}%\'" get Caption,ExecutablePath,Processid,CommandLine'.format('chrome.exe'))

process_info = getoutput('wmic process where "ProcessID={}" get Caption,ExecutablePath,Processid,CommandLine'.format(14520))
```