# Where does a file gets stored that came with a .exe file on Windows 10/11?

Tags: python, exe, nuitka

So I have made this python file which I want to compile (it's called ElPatron) to a .exe file with Nuitka.
I did it correctly and this is the dist folder that came with that (using the --standalone argument that Nuitka has)

This is the nuitka command I used:

```
.\python.exe -m nuitka --mingw64 .\ElPatron.py --standalone --onefile --windows-disable-console --windows-icon-from-ico=pdf.ico --include-data-file=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\example.pdf=example.pdf
```

I included the pdf in the exe using the --include-data-file argument from Nuitka

[image: Dist folder that nuitka has created]

The problem I have now is that I don't know where this(the example.pdf) get's stored when the ElPatron.exe is executed. I want to know this so I can call it inside my Python project.

**The question**

Where does the example.pdf get stored when a windows computer executes the .exe (containing the pdf)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the [Nuitka documentation](https://pypi.org/project/Nuitka/#use-case-4-program-distribution), it says:

> ```sh
> # Create a binary that unpacks into a temporary folder
> python -m nuitka --onefile program.py
> ```
>
> Note
>
> There are more platform specific options, e.g. related to icons,
> splash screen, and version information, consider the `--help` output
> for the details of these and check the section “Good Looks”.
>
> Again, on Windows, for the temporary file directory, by default the
> user one is used, however this is overridable with a path
> specification given in
> `--windows-onefile-tempdir-spec=%TEMP%\\onefile_%PID%_%TIME%` which is
> the default and asserts that the temporary directories created cannot
> collide.

So, I think the output should show up as a subdirectory in `%TEMP%` as described, which should be the path `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\`.

If you want to use the default path, you'll have to find the dynamically-named subfolder (**`onefile_%PID%_%TIME%`**) within `%TEMP%` in Python, and you can [get the current process ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3853703/2415524), then use a fuzzy pattern or something, as you won't be able to know the exact time. Otherwise, set a custom path.

Comment: So the PDF file should be in the TEMP file?

Comment: @Coder It should be in a dynamically-named *subfolder* in the Temp folder. They do this so that if you run it multiple times, it won't overwrite the file. If you changed the path to something like `%TEMP%\\onefile` (without the PID and TIME variables), then every time you run the program, the file would be overwritten, or if you run multiple processes, the file might be locked.

Comment: I got it using the argument you suggested! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A janky way of doing this might be:

```
def resource_path(self,relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for python file and compiled exe """
    if not sys.argv[0].endswith('exe'): return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]),relative_path)
    else: 
        if not hasattr(self,'respth'):
            temp_appd=os.path.join(os.getenv('localappdata'),'Temp')
            resdict={}
            for item in os.listdir(temp_appd):
                if len(re.findall('''onefile_\d+_\d+''',item))>0:
                    resdict[re.findall('''onefile_\d+_(\d+)''',item)[0]]=item
            self.respth=resdict[max(list(resdict.keys()))]
            logging.info('path set to '+os.path.join(os.getenv('localappdata'),'Temp',self.respth,relative_path))
        return os.path.join(os.getenv('localappdata'),'Temp',self.respth,relative_path)
```